# Flutter Plugin , CMakeList, Linking Problem

Tags: flutter, plugins

I am trying out creating a  Flutter Plugin on Ubuntu 18.04 .

1. Generated the plugin for linux platform...flutter create ...
2. Added a new class file(linux_recorder.cc which defines 'LinuxRecorder' class) and header file (linux/include/plugin) in linux directory
3. referenced the new class file header in 'xxx_plugin.cc'
4. flutter run -v =>
   it compiles...
   BUT at linking stage gives the error

   "plugins/vc_sound/libvc_sound_plugin.so: undefined reference to
   `LinuxRecorder::Start()' "

What am I doing wrong ? Do I have to include something in CMakeList.txt ? if yes, how (not much into CMakeList)
Please help

****UPDATE****
I included the class definition in the xxx_plugin.cc itself and everything went perfectly fine ..compiled and ran the app..

Of course , it is not the right way. It also points very much to the fact that Flutter is not refreshing the CMakeList ??? Any clues ?